# Fixing Index Fragmentation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Here is the fragmentation status on indexed tables:

[image]

And here is my `PageDefinition` table:

[image]

Any suggestion what possible changes I can made in this to low down the fragmentation. I am doing this first time so solution with reason will be very helpful.also please let me know if I need to add some more detail here.

Thanx

Comment: `CHAR(36)` as your PK seems excessive - it's a fixed-length, space-padded, 36-byte field - that'll blow up all your non-clustered indices for nothing. Try to use a more appropriate datatype for your PK/CK - something like `INT IDENTITY` - see [Kimberly Tripp's blog post on what a good PK/CK is](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) - it should be (a) narrow, (b) unique, (c) static, (d) ever-increasing (the "nuse" pricinciple)

Comment: no, it is a Guid.NewGuid passed from code.

Comment: That's even worse - but it's stored as `char(36)` according to your screenshot....

Answer (score 1):

Primary reason for fragmentation is pagesplits. Insert of new records or updating existing records might have resulted in changes in the way data allocated in a page

Good Presentation - http://devconnections.com/updates/LasVegas_Fall10/SQL/Randal-SQL-SDB306-Fragmentation.pdf

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/27/sql-server-2005-find-index-fragmentation-details-slow-index-performance/

You can provide fillfactor depending on updates/inserts done on table. Example - If you table is read only and no update might take place you can provide 100% fill factor. This would provide allocation so that your inserts/updates does not cause framgmentation.

70% you can configure to experiment with. Rebuilding index is another solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Kimberly Tripp - the *Queen of Indexing* - has a ton of great blog post on how to select a **good** clustering key (in SQL Server, the primary key is - by default - your clustering key).

Check them out, read them, learn them - obey them! :-)

- [GUIDs as Primary and Clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap......    THAT'S NOT THE POINT!!!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

Basically, just read her whole blog - everything on indexing, clustered indices and so on.

Your clustering key (and thus by default - your primary key) should be:

- **narrow** - 4 byte INT is great, anything beyond 16 byte (GUID) is a massive waste of space
- **unique** - read her blog posts on why
- **static** - never change (if possible)
- **ever-increasing** (typically: `INT IDENTITY`) to avoid page splits which cause most of the fragmentation